# What is the difference between sorting by date column versus custom sort column?

Tags: sorting, powerbi

I am looking at a Power BI model and the sort is based on a sortcolumn as shown in the below screenshot.

My question is - What is the difference between sorting by date column versus custom sort column?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that the **Sort** column considers year and month only, while sorting by **Date** will consider days and hours too.

Comment: So I need to have 1 sort column you yearmonth and another for yearweek?